# how to convert textbox data to integer in python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, integer, selenium-chromedriver

I am struggling to get the text from a textbox, convert it to an integer, multiply by 1.2 and then re-insert it back into the textbox.

I originally got an error saying I couldn't convert it to an integer (even though the string just said '2000') so I tried converting it to float and *then* to an integer, but now I'm getting 'ValueError: could not convert string to float'.

Any ideas what's going wrong? I'll attach the HTML of the textbox and my python.

HTML:

```
<input id="radius" ng-model="geoCtrl.lineRadius" 
type="text" placeholder="Desired radius from each point of the list" 
maxlength="100" name="targeting[geolocation][radius]" 
ng-class="{'val-ignore': geoCtrl.options !== 'geo'}" 
class="col-lg-12 attr-input ng-pristine ng-valid">
```

Python:

```
#code to find radius, multiply it by 1.2, then enter new radius into textbox
browser.find_element_by_id('radius')
first_radius_20percent = browser.find_element_by_id('radius')
current_radius = float(first_radius_20percent.get_attribute('value'))
current_radius = int(first_radius_20percent.get_attribute('value'))
new_radius = int(current_radius*1.2)
first_radius_20percent.clear()
first_radius_20percent.send_keys(new_radius)
```

Comment: What does `first_radius_20percent.get_attribute('value')` return? `'2000'` or do you only see it in the website?

Comment: @Guy it returns u'2000' EDIT: actually when I print `first_radius_20percent.get_attribute('value')` it just prints '2000'

Answer (score 0):

There might be some unicode characters mixed in the returned value, you can get rid of them with `encode('ascii', 'ignore')`

```
current_radius = int(first_radius_20percent.get_attribute('value').encode('ascii', 'ignore'))
```

Comment: I tried this but now I'm getting the error ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Comment: @booooooky what is the value in the error message? `...with base 10: b'2000.0'`?

Comment: there isn't any value being given just 'base 10: '' - would this suggest no value is being pulled? why?

Comment: @booooooky you said `first_radius_20percent.get_attribute('value')` returns a value. You can also try `value = ''.join(c for c in value if c.isprintable())` where `value` is the value returned from `get_attribute`.

Comment: yes, it returns "u'2000'" (without the outer quotations)

Comment: @booooooky what is the full error message, the original one when you tried converting it to an `int`?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 59, in <module>
ValueError:  could not convert string to float:

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205594/discussion-between-guy-and-booooooky).

Answer (score 0):

As per the HTML you have shared:

```
<input id="radius" ng-model="geoCtrl.lineRadius" type="text" placeholder="Desired radius from each point of the list" maxlength="100" name="targeting[geolocation][radius]" ng-class="{'val-ignore': geoCtrl.options !== 'geo'}" class="col-lg-12 attr-input ng-pristine ng-valid">
```

I don't see the `value` e.g. **2000** but a `placeholder` as *Desired radius from each point of the list* within the element. However as per your question as the element is an an [Angular](https://angular.io/) element so to extract the `value` of the element you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `element_to_be_clickable()`.

Further, as you have to multiply the extracted value by **1.2** it would be better to convert the value returned from `get_attribute()` into `float` but while invoking `send_keys()` you have to convert into a `string` again and you use the following solution:

- Code Block:

  ```
  driver.get('https://www.google.com/')
  first_radius_20percent = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "q")))
  # current_float_radius = float(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "radius"))).get_attribute('value'))
  # or
  # current_float_radius = float(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#radius"))).get_attribute('value'))
  current_float_radius = float("2000")
  new_radius = float(current_float_radius*1.2)
  first_radius_20percent.send_keys(str(new_radius))
  ```

Browser Snapshot:

[image: float]

Comment: Did you read the question? *I tried converting it to float and then to an integer, but now I'm getting 'ValueError: could not convert string to float'*

Comment: @booooooky Got a chance to evaluate this answer?

Comment: @DebanjanB will do now, give me 2 secs :)

Comment: @DebanjanB just on this one, I will need it to read the textbox first as the value won't always be 2000?

Comment: Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.

Answer (score 0):

so the solution wasn't an issue with datatype, my code was pulling the value for the textbox as soon as it loaded, but the '2000' was only being populated after half a second or so. The solution I found was to just add in a time delay before carrying out the python script in question.

Thank you for all the help though!